# Type used in a using statement should be implicitly convertible to IDisposable

Tags: using-statement, veracode

I have the following logic:

```
try
{
   using (var contents = new StreamReader(file.InputStream).ReadToEnd()) 
   {
       var rows = contents.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
       rows.ForEach(r => mids.Add(r.Split(',')[0]));
   }
}
catch(IOException e)
{}
finally
{
   contents = null;
}
```

In the `using` statement I have an error in the question. It happened probably because I use `.ReadToEnd()` method.

Without the  `using` statement I would need to use `try/catch/finally` for a clean up (to fix `veracode` resource clean up issue)

How can I fix that, so I don't need to use `try\catch\finally` and use only the `using` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, `using` should be used with object which implements [`IDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=net-5.0) interface. You calling [`ReadToEnd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readtoend?view=net-5.0) method which returns `string` and `contents` is not a `IDisposable` (because string is not).
You should use it like this:

```cs
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(file.InputStream)) 
{
    var contents = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    // Some actions
}
```

You want to clean up `StreamReader`, `contents` will be collected by GC when method will finished because it has type `string`.